# Entity Framework Add and Update

Tags: sql, entity-framework, addition

Is there a fast way to add new and update existing rows in my database using EF6?

Say I have an

```
IEnumerable<User>
```

with 5 new users and 2 users with some updated fields. How can I add and update users?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called `.AddOrUpdate()`.

[MSDN Link.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514(v=vs.103).aspx)

You'd call it with something along those lines:

```
foreach(var user in Users)
{
   //Don't use the PrimaryKey in SomeField. 
   context.Users.AddOrUpdate(u => u.SomeField, user);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```